# Disable logs in agenda npm

Tags: javascript, agenda

```
agenda.every("3 minutes", "delete old users");
await agenda.start();
```

I am setting up a job scheduler using Agenda.js and Node, backed with MongoDB. So far it's working as expected. However, I'm getting agenda logs in my console, so how to disable the agenda log

[image]